# C: socket connection timeout

Tags: c, network-programming

I have a simple program to check if a port is open, but I want to shorten the timeout length on the socket connection because the default is far too long. I'm not sure how to do this though. Here's the code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    u_short port;                /* user specified port number */
    char addr[1023];             /* will be a copy of the address entered by u */
    struct sockaddr_in address;  /* the libc network address data structure */
    short int sock = -1;         /* file descriptor for the network socket */

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s <port_num> <address>", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[2]); /* assign the address */
    address.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));            /* translate int2port num */

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&address,sizeof(address)) == 0) {
        printf("%i is open\n", port);
    }  
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You added in your answer "fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)"
Note that after this the next socket read becomes also nonblocking!

Comment: Interestingly enough, it is mentioned in [this man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/connect) but in the one I have installed on Ubuntu, you have to have the wit of reading the info about the `EINPROGRESS` error to understand that the socket can be non-blocking to do an asynchronous connection.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This article might help:

[Connect with timeout (or another use for select() )](http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=3196.)

Looks like you put the socket into non-blocking mode until you've connected, and then put it back into blocking mode once the connection's established.

```c
void connect_w_to(void) { 
  int res; 
  struct sockaddr_in addr; 
  long arg; 
  fd_set myset; 
  struct timeval tv; 
  int valopt; 
  socklen_t lon; 

  // Create socket 
  soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
  if (soc < 0) { 
     fprintf(stderr, "Error creating socket (%d %s)\n", errno, strerror(errno)); 
     exit(0); 
  } 

  addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
  addr.sin_port = htons(2000); 
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1"); 

  // Set non-blocking 
  if( (arg = fcntl(soc, F_GETFL, NULL)) < 0) { 
     fprintf(stderr, "Error fcntl(..., F_GETFL) (%s)\n", strerror(errno)); 
     exit(0); 
  } 
  arg |= O_NONBLOCK; 
  if( fcntl(soc, F_SETFL, arg) < 0) { 
     fprintf(stderr, "Error fcntl(..., F_SETFL) (%s)\n", strerror(errno)); 
     exit(0); 
  } 
  // Trying to connect with timeout 
  res = connect(soc, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)); 
  if (res < 0) { 
     if (errno == EINPROGRESS) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "EINPROGRESS in connect() - selecting\n"); 
        do { 
           tv.tv_sec = 15; 
           tv.tv_usec = 0; 
           FD_ZERO(&myset); 
           FD_SET(soc, &myset); 
           res = select(soc+1, NULL, &myset, NULL, &tv); 
           if (res < 0 && errno != EINTR) { 
              fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno)); 
              exit(0); 
           } 
           else if (res > 0) { 
              // Socket selected for write 
              lon = sizeof(int); 
              if (getsockopt(soc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void*)(&valopt), &lon) < 0) { 
                 fprintf(stderr, "Error in getsockopt() %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno)); 
                 exit(0); 
              } 
              // Check the value returned... 
              if (valopt) { 
                 fprintf(stderr, "Error in delayed connection() %d - %s\n", valopt, strerror(valopt) 
); 
                 exit(0); 
              } 
              break; 
           } 
           else { 
              fprintf(stderr, "Timeout in select() - Cancelling!\n"); 
              exit(0); 
           } 
        } while (1); 
     } 
     else { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno)); 
        exit(0); 
     } 
  } 
  // Set to blocking mode again... 
  if( (arg = fcntl(soc, F_GETFL, NULL)) < 0) { 
     fprintf(stderr, "Error fcntl(..., F_GETFL) (%s)\n", strerror(errno)); 
     exit(0); 
  } 
  arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK); 
  if( fcntl(soc, F_SETFL, arg) < 0) { 
     fprintf(stderr, "Error fcntl(..., F_SETFL) (%s)\n", strerror(errno)); 
     exit(0); 
  } 
  // I hope that is all 
}
```

Comment: Nice.  This is a better suggestion than mine.

Comment: This is a very good answer, why did you make it community wiki? You should earn some reputation for suggesting the resource.

Comment: The forum linked to seems to have changed their software, so the link is dead now.

Comment: Note: although this answer is deemed the right one, caf's solution below not only explains the strategy but provides working code.

Comment: This solution (and it appears most others) has a flaw in that, when `signal`/`poll` is interrupted with EINTR, it starts the timeout back at 0, even though some time has already elapsed. See my solution which addresses this.

Comment: Connection timeout using select() like this does not work when fd > 1024 on most of the linux or unix hosts.

Comment: What is the point of the "do while" loop here? It seems this loop could only ever possibly run once.

Comment: Does not handle signals appropriately. The code is way to short to handle all the select() corner cases. Note that select() may block on non-blocking sockets, and it may fall through on blocking sockets, and it may spuriously return without fds getting writable. The  semantics of the returned timeout is undefined and thus cannot be relied upon. Using select() is difficult. The code above may in fact block indefinitely since the timeout is restarted with each signal, as Jay already said.

Answer (score 76):

Set the socket non-blocking, and use `select()` (which takes a timeout parameter).  If a non-blocking socket is trying to connect, then `select()` will indicate that the socket is writeable when the `connect()` finishes (either successfully or unsuccessfully).  You then use `getsockopt()` to determine the outcome of the `connect()`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    u_short port;                /* user specified port number */
    char *addr;                  /* will be a pointer to the address */
    struct sockaddr_in address;  /* the libc network address data structure */
    short int sock = -1;         /* file descriptor for the network socket */
    fd_set fdset;
    struct timeval tv;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s <port_num> <address>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    port = atoi(argv[1]);
    addr = argv[2];

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr); /* assign the address */
    address.sin_port = htons(port);            /* translate int2port num */

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));

    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(sock, &fdset);
    tv.tv_sec = 10;             /* 10 second timeout */
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    if (select(sock + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv) == 1)
    {
        int so_error;
        socklen_t len = sizeof so_error;

        getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &len);

        if (so_error == 0) {
            printf("%s:%d is open\n", addr, port);
        }
    }

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works in *nix, but does not work in Windows.  In Windows, you determine if the socket is connected by looking at the return value of "select" in your code above.  In windows, select returns 1 if the connection completed, or it returns 0 if the connection was not successful.  If you look at so_error, then Windows always returns 0, even when the connection failed.  That's windows for you, as they say.

Comment: What if I don't want to use non-blocking mode for other socket operations (like read, write)? Can I clear `O_NONBLOCK` flag after socket is connected? If it is possible, is It safe?

Comment: @anton_rh: Yes, it is safe to clear `O_NONBLOCK` and put the socket back into blocking mode.

Comment: It is also much better to use poll then select. Nobody should use "select" in new software anymore because it is broken when you increase the number of open file descriptors per process behind a very limited number. Also using SOCK_NONBLOCK directly in the socket call is recommended (maybe also use SOCK_CLOEXEC)

Comment: I realize this thread is very old, but I do have a question about your solution: I notice that you don't check the return value of your connect() call. I've tried replicating your example, and I get an error connect() returned errno 119 "Connection already in progress". This is only true when I use the fcntl() call; I don't get an error otherwise. So...is this expected behavior? Thank you.

Comment: @mzimmers: It's expected that it would return non-zero with `errno` set to `EINPROGRESS`.  You could check for other errors there if you like, but any other error should also be retrieved by the `getsockopt()` call later anyway.

Comment: @deltamind106 maybe something changed, or maybe you tried in different situations, but in the basic case where `select` returns 0 because of a timeout because the remote end simply doesn't exist, `so_error` in the code above gets set to 10061 a.k.a. `WSAECONNREFUSED` a.k.a 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.'. In other words: works fine for me on Windows (10).

Comment: @deltamind106 That is not correct. `select()` always returns the number of sockets that are ready for whatever operation they were selected for. Same in Unix, Linux, Windows, AIX, HP/UX, MacOS, Solaris, ... anything you name.

Answer (score 33):

Here is a modern `connect_with_timeout` implementation, using `poll`, with proper error and signal handling:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <time.h>

int connect_with_timeout(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen, unsigned int timeout_ms) {
    int rc = 0;
    // Set O_NONBLOCK
    int sockfd_flags_before;
    if((sockfd_flags_before=fcntl(sockfd,F_GETFL,0)<0)) return -1;
    if(fcntl(sockfd,F_SETFL,sockfd_flags_before | O_NONBLOCK)<0) return -1;
    // Start connecting (asynchronously)
    do {
        if (connect(sockfd, addr, addrlen)<0) {
            // Did connect return an error? If so, we'll fail.
            if ((errno != EWOULDBLOCK) && (errno != EINPROGRESS)) {
                rc = -1;
            }
            // Otherwise, we'll wait for it to complete.
            else {
                // Set a deadline timestamp 'timeout' ms from now (needed b/c poll can be interrupted)
                struct timespec now;
                if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now)<0) { rc=-1; break; }
                struct timespec deadline = { .tv_sec = now.tv_sec,
                                             .tv_nsec = now.tv_nsec + timeout_ms*1000000l};
                // Wait for the connection to complete.
                do {
                    // Calculate how long until the deadline
                    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now)<0) { rc=-1; break; }
                    int ms_until_deadline = (int)(  (deadline.tv_sec  - now.tv_sec)*1000l
                                                  + (deadline.tv_nsec - now.tv_nsec)/1000000l);
                    if(ms_until_deadline<0) { rc=0; break; }
                    // Wait for connect to complete (or for the timeout deadline)
                    struct pollfd pfds[] = { { .fd = sockfd, .events = POLLOUT } };
                    rc = poll(pfds, 1, ms_until_deadline);
                    // If poll 'succeeded', make sure it *really* succeeded
                    if(rc>0) {
                        int error = 0; socklen_t len = sizeof(error);
                        int retval = getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len);
                        if(retval==0) errno = error;
                        if(error!=0) rc=-1;
                    }
                }
                // If poll was interrupted, try again.
                while(rc==-1 && errno==EINTR);
                // Did poll timeout? If so, fail.
                if(rc==0) {
                    errno = ETIMEDOUT;
                    rc=-1;
                }
            }
        }
    } while(0);
    // Restore original O_NONBLOCK state
    if(fcntl(sockfd,F_SETFL,sockfd_flags_before)<0) return -1;
    // Success
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: +1000. Wow. I have to say this is the most underrated answer currently on StackOverflow!

Comment: +1 This is absolutely beautiful.  Simple, extremely effective, completely self-contained, documented, and gets away from using select.

Comment: among other answers this is the one i choose. non blocking + poll.

Comment: Nice! As always, if the solution using select() is less than 20 lines long it is usually broken. select() has difficult semantics.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks. I'm still left wondering why there isn't a `connect` function which allows me to offer a timeout value as a parameter. Seems like a common need. As it stands, it appears that if I want something other than the default timeout, I have to replace my one `connect` call with a huge amount of code.

Comment: Not portable, will not work on Windows

Comment: Whats the point of do..while(0) in the outermost loop ? What is the author trying to achieve here ?

Comment: @moi `break` in it is the same as `goto end` where `end` is the next line after the `while (0)`

Answer (score 32):

The answers about using `select()`/`poll()` are right and code should be written this way to be portable.

However, since you're on Linux, you can do this:

```
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
//...

int synRetries = 2; // Send a total of 3 SYN packets => Timeout ~7s
setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_SYNCNT, &synRetries, sizeof(synRetries));
```

See `man 7 tcp` and `man setsockopt`.

I used this to speed up the connect-timeout in a program I needed to patch quickly. Hacking it to timeout via `select()`/`poll()` was not an option.

---

The empirical values observed by tcpdump on win10 22H2 Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
`Linux 23DKMN3 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

| Retries | Timeout on wsl2 (second) | Timeout on native Ubuntu20.04 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.049923 | 1.011340 |
| 1 | 3.129942 | 3.027308 |
| 2 | 7.209805 | 7.123300 |
| 3 | 15.859880 | 15.315300 |
| 4 | 32.489877 | 31.443295 |
| 5 | 65.139792 | 63.699309 |
| 6 | 130.43962 | 129.235296 |

Comment: Nice! Simple and useful! Include to add: #include <netinet/tcp.h>

Comment: synRetries = 1 results in ~3s timeout (empirically) and synRetries = 0 unfortunately in ~127s timeout (not in ~1s as one would expect). synRetries = 2 ~7s timeout confirmed.

Comment: @JohannesOvermann, could you confirm your tests again? I updated the answer with my test result but it seems like a bit different from yours (your is off by one). Where retries = 1 results in ~ 1 sec and retries  = 2 results in ~3s. It's timed by tcpdump.

Comment: I have never used the win10 Linux subsystem. All TCP stacks and OSes behave differently. This is totally non-portable. So the numbers will never agree.

Answer (score 10):

On Linux you can also use:

```
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec  = 7;  // after 7 seconds connect() will timeout
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));
connect(...)
```

Don't forget to clear `SO_SNDTIMEO` after `connect()` if you don't need it.

Comment: I prefer the form above with the SOL_SOCKET in the setsockopt.

Answer (score 5):

This one has parametrized ip, port, timeout in seconds, handle connection errors and give you connection time in milliseconds:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct sockaddr_in addr_s;
    char *addr;
    short int fd=-1;
    int port;
    fd_set fdset;
    struct timeval tv;
    int rc;
    int so_error;
    socklen_t len;
    struct timespec tstart={0,0}, tend={0,0};
    int seconds;

    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <ip> <port> <timeout_seconds>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    addr = argv[1];
    port = atoi(argv[2]);
    seconds = atoi(argv[3]);

    addr_s.sin_family = AF_INET; // utilizzo IPv4
    addr_s.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr);
    addr_s.sin_port = htons(port);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tstart);

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); // setup non blocking socket

    // make the connection
    rc = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr_s, sizeof(addr_s));
    if ((rc == -1) && (errno != EINPROGRESS)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return 1;
    }
    if (rc == 0) {
        // connection has succeeded immediately
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tend);
        printf("socket %s:%d connected. It took %.5f seconds\n",
            addr, port, (((double)tend.tv_sec + 1.0e-9*tend.tv_nsec) - ((double)tstart.tv_sec + 1.0e-9*tstart.tv_nsec)));

        close(fd);
        return 0;
    } /*else {
        // connection attempt is in progress
    } */

    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(fd, &fdset);
    tv.tv_sec = seconds;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    rc = select(fd + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv);
    switch(rc) {
    case 1: // data to read
        len = sizeof(so_error);

        getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &len);

        if (so_error == 0) {
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tend);
            printf("socket %s:%d connected. It took %.5f seconds\n",
                addr, port, (((double)tend.tv_sec + 1.0e-9*tend.tv_nsec) - ((double)tstart.tv_sec + 1.0e-9*tstart.tv_nsec)));
            close(fd);
            return 0;
        } else { // error
            printf("socket %s:%d NOT connected: %s\n", addr, port, strerror(so_error));
        }
        break;
    case 0: //timeout
        fprintf(stderr, "connection timeout trying to connect to %s:%d\n", addr, port);
        break;
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The two socket options `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SNDTIMEO` have no effect on `connect`.  Below is a link to the screenshot which includes this explanation, here I am just briefing it. The apt way of implementing timeouts with `connect` are using `signal`  or `select or poll`.

#### Signals

`connect` can be interrupted by a self generated signal `SIGALRM` by using syscall (wrapper) `alarm`. But, a signal disposition should be installed for the same signal otherwise the program would be terminated. The code goes like this...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<errno.h>

static void signal_handler(int signo)
{
    return; // Do nothing just interrupt.
}

int main()
{
    /* Register signal handler */

    struct sigaction act, oact;

    act.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;

#ifdef SA_INTERRUPT
    act.sa_flags |= SA_INTERRUPT;
#endif

    if(sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, &oact) < 0)  // Error registering signal handler.
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error registering signal disposition\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Prepare your socket and sockaddr structures */

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr* servaddr;

    /* Implementing timeout connect */

    int sec = 30;

    if(alarm(sec) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Already timer was set\n");

    if(connect(sockfd, servaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0)
    {
        if(errno == EINTR)
            fprintf(stderr, "Connect timeout\n");
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Connect failed\n");

        close(sockfd);
    
        exit(1);
    }

    alarm(0);  /* turn off the alarm */

    sigaction(SIGALRM, &oact, NULL);  /* Restore the default actions of SIGALRM */

    /* Use socket */


    /* End program */

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Select or Poll

As already some users provided nice explanation on how to use `select` to achieve `connect` timeout, it would not be necessary for me to reiterate the same. `poll` can be used in the same way. However, there are few mistakes that are common in all of the answers, which I would like to address.

- Even though socket is non-blocking, if the server to which we are connecting is on the same local machine, `connect` may return with success. So it is advised to check the return value of `connect` before calling `select`.
- Berkeley-derived implementations (and POSIX) have the following rules for non-blocking sockets and `connect`.

  1. When the connection completes successfully, the descriptor becomes writable (p. 531 of TCPv2).
  2. When the connection establishment encounters an error, the descriptor becomes both readable and writable (p. 530 of TCPv2).

So the code should handle these cases, here I just code the necessary modifications.

```
/* All the code stays */

/* Modifications at connect */

int conn_ret = connect(sockfd, servaddr, sizeof(struct sockdaddr));

if(conn_ret == 0)
    goto done;

/* Modifications at select */

int sec = 30;
for( ; ; )
{
    struct timeval timeo;
    timeo.tv_sec = sec;
    timeo.tv_usec = 0;

    fd_set wr_set, rd_set;
    FDZERO(&wr_set);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &wr_set);
    rd_set = wr_set;
    int sl_ret = select(sockfd + 1, &rd_set, &wr_set, NULL, &timeo);

    /* All the code stays */
}


done:
    
    /* Use your socket */
```

[image: Text from Unix Network Programming Volume 1]

Comment: The answer incorrectly state that SNDTIMEO does not apply to 'connect'. This is not true - the "man 7 socket" page clealy state that using SO_SNDTIMEO will result in EINPROGRESS for connect.

Answer (score 4):

Is there anything wrong with [Nahuel Greco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49698179/8807809)'s solution aside from the compilation error?

If I change one line

```
// Compilation error
setsockopt(fd, SO_SNDTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));
```

to

```
// Fixed?
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));
```

then it seems to work as advertised - `socket()` returns a timeout error.

Resulting code:

```
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec  = 7;  // after 7 seconds connect() will timeout
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));
connect(...)
```

I'm not versed enough to know the tradeoffs are between a send timeout and a non-blocking socket, but I'm curious to learn.

Comment: if you plan to use the socket in blocking mode, you will make fewer syscalls by implementing the SO_SNDTIMEO solution rather than putting the socket into non-blocking mode, connect and then putting back in blocking mode. Seems a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is over a decade old and everybody and their mother has answered it, but there is a very simple and easy solution to this that I'm surprised hasn't been mentioned here. Granted, this is a Linux-only solution.

You can specify an exact connect timeout, down to the millisecond, simply by setting the `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT` socket option.

Per the tcp(7) [manual page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html):

> This option takes an unsigned int as an argument.  When the value is
> greater than 0, it specifies the maximum amount of time in
> milliseconds that transmitted data may remain unacknowledged, or
> buffered data may remain untransmitted (due to zero window size)
> before TCP will forcibly close the corresponding connection and return
> ETIMEDOUT to the application.  If the option value is specified as 0,
> TCP will use the system default.

Here's a quick and dirty (and working) code example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sockFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    
    // Set the socket connect timeout to 5 seconds
    uint32_t userTimeout = 5000;
    socklen_t userTimeoutLen = sizeof(userTimeout);
    
    setsockopt(sockFD, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_USER_TIMEOUT, &userTimeout, userTimeoutLen);
    
    // To test connection timeout, try connecting to an IP that's currently unused
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port = 0x162C; // Port 5676
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = 0xC0A80113; // IP 192.168.1.19
    
    int conRes = connect(sockFD, (sockaddr*) &sa, sizeof(sa));
    
    if(conRes == 0)
    {
        // After the connection succeeds, you can set the timeout back to the default of 0
        userTimeout = 0;
        setsockopt(sockFD, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_USER_TIMEOUT, &userTimeout, userTimeoutLen);
        
        printf("Connect success\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connect failed.\n");
        perror("Error");
    }
    
    close(sockFD);
    
    return 0;
}
```

If I run the above code using the `time` command to measure how long the program executes for, we get the following:

```
user@laptop:~/code/test$ time ./main 
Connect failed.
Error: Connection timed out

real    0m5.017s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.005s
```