# Socket: Connect will spend 2 minutes looking for IP before it timesOut. How to reduce that time?

Tags: c, sockets, timeout, connect

I want to reduce the allowed timeOut time that socket:connect will take to look up an IP/Port to connect to? On some network routers like Netgear that use IP 10.0.0.x only takes less than a second to timeout.

Note:  "select" comes later

```
host = gethostbyname("xxx");//invalid IP, 

memcpy(&(sin.sin_addr), host->h_addr, host->h_length);
sin.sin_family = host->h_addrtype;
sin.sin_port = htons(4000);

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
hConnect = connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));//sits here for 2 minutes before moving on to the next line of code

bConn = 0;// no connect
if (hConnect == 0) {
    bConn = 1;// connect made
}
```

thx

Comment: what OS are you using?  Where's the rest of the code, I need to see a little bit more than this.  Could you be a bit more vague?  What is the question?

Comment: There is an interesting asynchronous approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1062035/694576

Comment: I am using a standard-c library... this repeats on PC or MAC or iPhone

Comment: here is an approach... but dangerous... put this in a thread, kill the thread in 5 seconds.  If the local IP exists, it should connect in a fraction of a second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: socket connection timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597608/c-socket-connection-timeout)

Comment: Btw: `gethostbyame()` and `gethostbyaddr()` are somehow deprecated. You might better use `getnameinfo()` and `getaddrinfo()`

Comment: Here is a good example:  http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=3196

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the socket to non-blocking prior to calling `connect()`, and then do a `select()` or `poll()` on it to find out any events going on on it.

Note: Using this setup you'll be getting a non-zero return from `connect()` and `errno` is set to `EINPROGRESS` in the case `connect()` returns without having connected but still is trying to do.

Please see the `ERRORS` section of `connect()`'s man page for more on this.

Comment: Yes sure, you do this also by using `setsockopt()` but not using `O_NONBLOCK`as for setting the non-blocking flag, but it's invers value `~O_NONBLOCK`...

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is in two steps:

1. connect() with O_NONBLOCK
2. use select() with a timeout