# connect() hang for long time upon connection refused

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I've a small agent that supposed to connect to server from time to time
first stage it opens a `socket`:

```
const char* hostname // e.g. "127.0.0.1"   
hostaddr = inet_addr(hostname);

    /* Ultra basic "connect to port 22 on localhost"
     * Your code is responsible for creating the socket establishing the
     * connection
     */ 
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(22);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = hostaddr;
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)(&sin),
                sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to connect!\n");
        return -1;
    }
```

when `ip-address` is not valid it seems that connect hangs for very long time
before failing

looking at the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/connect) provide some data on the subject but not how to overpass it

My question is why and how can I add timeout for it (or any other solution)

Comment: 'Connection refused' happens within seconds. Did you mean 'connect timeout'?

Comment: 'I've a small agent' - if it's a subsystem within your app, can you not just thread it all off?

Comment: i've many VMs that request update/info from server , this section does "validation" on the connection before connecting

Comment: Which s a complete waste of time. You should just connect, not try to predict the future.

Comment: @EJP I respect your opinion but you wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597608/c-socket-connection-timeout#2597774)

> Put the socket into non-blocking mode until you've connected, and then put it back into blocking mode once the connection's established.

Comment: The correct thing to do was to mark this question as a duplicate of another qurstion, not quote an answer from that other question. You didn't even quote the best answer, as several of the other answers explained how to implement the timeout, but the one you quoted does not.